# SSRS 2008 reference an embedded image in custom code

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to do some drawling on an embedded image before displaying it on a report.  Basically I want to draw lines on it.  I have done some searching and found answers on how to get the drawing namespace to work via custom code and have tested drawing on a blank "canvas" but have not been able to find anything on how to draw on an embedded image.  I expect something like referencing report variables (Report.Variables![variableName]).  Report.Images does not work.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeff